# how to change line color in Lightweight charts to gradient

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, charts, colors

I am using Lightweight charts library with Next JS. I want to customize the line color in my chart to gradient, Is it possible ? as I have searched a lot and couldnt find an answer even in the documentation. Here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const chart = createChart(chartRef.current, {
      layout: {
        background: { type: ColorType.Solid, color: 'transparent' },
        textColor: 'white',
      },
      height: 150,
      leftPriceScale: {
        visible: true,
      },
      rightPriceScale: {
        visible: false,
      },
      grid: {
        horzLines: {
          visible: false,
        },
        vertLines: {
          visible: false,
        },
      },
    });
    const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries({
      color: '#DFDFDF', <------ change this color to gradient
      lineStyle: LineStyle.Solid,
      lineType: LineType.Curved,
      priceLineVisible: false,
      crosshairMarkerBackgroundColor:'#DFDFDF',
    });

    const data: any = [
      { value: 0, time: 1642425322 },
      { value: 8, time: 1642511722 },
      { value: 10, time: 1642598122 },
      { value: 20, time: 1642684522 },
      { value: 3, time: 1642770922 },
      { value: 43, time: 1642857322 },
      { value: 41, time: 1642943722 },
      { value: 43, time: 1643030122 },
      { value: 56, time: 1643116522 },
      { value: 46, time: 1643202922 },
    ];

    lineSeries.setData(data);

    chart.timeScale().fitContent();
  }, []);
```

Change line color in lightweight charts